# what is the problem in this while_loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

For example, if limit is 40, your code should set the nearest_square to 36.

```
limit = 40
product =0
nearest_square=product
while nearest_square <limit:
    product += 1   
    nearest_square **= product

print(nearest_square)
```

Comment: I fixed your code formatting, please make sure it matches your actual code indentation.

Comment: Your loop executes one time too many. When `nearest_square` is `36`, the condition will be true, so it will go into the loop and multiply `nearest_square` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you add one more `print()` to inspect `nearest_square` and run:

```py
limit = 40
product = 0
nearest_square = product
while nearest_square < limit:
    product += 1
    nearest_square **= product
    print(nearest_square)

print(nearest_square)
```

You'll see that it's always `0` and never changes (b/c `product` keeps getting multiplied by `0`).